# Google Drive permissions for shared spreadsheet export by API V3

Tags: google-drive-api

How to set permissions for google drive shared spreadsheet for allow export it by Drive API V3? (spreadsheet shared for you by other user and you can get export it by GUI)

I've got this:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Insufficient Permission",
    "reason" : "insufficientPermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "Insufficient Permission"
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:146)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1065)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at Quickstart.main(Quickstart.java:121)
```

Comment: the code caused exception is: service.files().export(i1.getId(),"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet").execute();

Answer (score 0):

Defined in the google support post:

> ["Insufficient permissions" or "System busy"](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2898334?hl=en)
>
> These errors mean that Chrome couldn't save the file to your computer.
>
> To fix the error:
>
> - Cancel the download and try again.
> - Instead of clicking the file to download, right-click the link and select **Save link as**.
> - Be sure to download files to a place on your computer you have access to, like your Desktop or Documents folder. You can [change
>     download locations](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95574).

To learn more about permissions, you can refer in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-permissions).

Here are the list of permission available in each file and folder in google drive.

- [type](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions#resource)
- [role](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions#resource)
- [emailAddress or domain](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions#resource)

> These values work together to limit the access appropriately. The type
>   limits access to a set of users. The email address and domain fields
>   specify which users can have access. Finally, the role gives these
>   users the ability to do something to the file, like read it. When
>   combined, these properties define a complete permission.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:
If you run java app firs time, you need installed web browser on running host, which opens and asks for confirm permissions and create /.credentials/gdrive/
StoredCredential. This file can be changed by single way - delete and recreate it by browser.  You can copy this file to GUI-less host for running of yours console app.